# HTTP Error 403.14 ASP configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this error while trying to initiate a project in ASP. I have already added

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

To the `Web.config` but I still get this error. Also, I have tried initiating the IIS Express by opening `appcmd.exe` but this did not fix it either. None of the solutions I have found worked for me so far.
Any ideas?.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Open IIS

Step 2. Go to the WebSite you are facing issue with.

Step 3. Click on Default Document Button, you will find it on the right side tab in IIS.

**Step 4. You can see a list of default documents, but your default page (aspx file) is not mentioned here and that is causing the issue.**

5. Add your file here. (For example: Index.aspx)

You can also add the following entry into the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
       <files>
         <add value="Index.aspx" />
       </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Hope it helps.